# How to implement different animation transitions between fragments of a view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am trying to figure out how to implement  different animation transitions between fragments of a view pager like zoom in, zoom out,fade in , fade out etc. But these animation should be random.

Comment: what do you mean by random??

Comment: random mean if i have 30 different fragment i need random animation while switching to other fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to write a class with all your transitions defined and then use Java ***Random*** class.

1)code would go something like this.

```
private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

    if (min >= max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

In your case, it would be

> getRandomNumberInRange(1,30)

2) Define your animation transitions as

> transition1(), transition2(), transition3(), etc...

3) And write a switch case in your Activity for fragment transitions.

```
switch(randomNumber)
{
  case 1: transform1();
   break;
  case 2: transform2(): 
  break;
.
.
default: transformX();
}
```

Comment: thanks karthik for your reply, can you please suggest the animation also i need atleast 30 type of different animation. I found one library https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers  which has 13 animation need 17 more ...

Comment: i think this has a little more - https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

Comment: you can always define your own transforms - https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.j0nlry5af



This could be a resource as well -  https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111

Comment: just one more problem animation seems to be too fast can we control animation time ? in addition to this can i enable swiping in the fragment of view pager i want my textview to be visible on each swipe for eg if fragment has 4 text view then user has to swipe 4 time to see the entire fragment then only viewpager next fragment should be visible on swiping how to implement this

Comment: can you give a sample app for random animation because I trying your logic for random animation but it will show stuck random animation.